# Modelling Company and Person Customers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails application uses STI where I have different types of companies and persons. For example I have suppliers, manufacturers and customers as types of Company. I have also employees, contacts and customers as types of People.

Now I want to refer to a Customer which can either be a Company Customer or a Person Customer. Which method can I use/should I use to combine these two different entities into one? So I can refer to a Customer, from an Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use:

```
Order      
   belongs_to :company
   belongs_to :person
end
```

And have two foreign keys - and then add some validations to make sure one of them is filled in, and then maybe add a 'customer' method which returns either the related company or person, depending which is used.

OR, create a separate Customer model (and table), which has those two same two foreign keys, and then Order can simply `belong_to :customer`. This second method may be preferably if you want to store additional data at the customer level (such as credit limit, or billing details), and may be cleaner long-term.

Alternative, you could reconsider your business logic, and insist that all orders belongs to a Person, even if that person is an employee of a Company and is purchasing on behalf of the company.

F